# ¿Cómo eliminar las filas duplicadas de una tabla en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

En mi base de datos tengo la tabla supplies:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de un tiempo trabajando en esta base de datos al volver abrir sql server y querer editar esta tabla, veo que se han duplicado todas las filas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber por qué pasó esto y como puedo eliminar las filas duplicadas, ya que al intentar eliminar sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda de ante mano.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir la estructura de la tabla? ¿tienes alguna idel del porqué se han duplicado? ¿De qué forma estás intentando eliminar los duplicados?

Comment: a pesar de que te demos un codigo sql para quitar los duplicados puede que tendras problemas si la base de datos tiene relaciones de esa tabla a otra

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El error pasa porque la fila que intentas eliminar tiene un duplicado exactamente igual, para borrar las filas exactamente iguales, te sugiero este Query:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE ....
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Este va a borrar exactamente un registro de la tabla, pero te sugiero que cheques por que se duplican los valores, ya que no es normal.

La otra opción que tienes si esque tienes muchos registros con filas exactamente iguales, es que crees una tabla nueva y en esta tabla incluyas los registros diferentes:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table)
```